# Having issues in connecting exchange online through PowerShell script. Error shows below

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Error being received when trying to connect:

```
New-ExoPSSession : One or more errors occurred.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\2.0.5\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:475 char:30
+ ... PSSession = New-ExoPSSession -ExchangeEnvironmentName $ExchangeEnviro ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-ExoPSSession], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.AggregateException,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellSnapin.NewExoPSSession
```

Comment: Hi - it would help us help you if you include the full command being run with context (excluding your credentials, of course)

Comment: Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin@arc.com

Comment: before it was shoing TLS error, after updating to TLS1.2, this error pops up.